# Youtube. Как вывести в список 5 лучший комментариев к видео

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, youtube, комментарии

Как ввести в список 5 лучших комментариев к видео в Youtube? Pytube или другими инструментами

Comment: Что значит _"лучших"_?

Comment: Те, которые больше всего пролайкали